# Alpha transparency in CaptureStream API for firefox and Chrome over Webrtc

Tags: html5-canvas, webrtc

I am trying to send canvas stream to Peerconnection using Capturestream API. I ran into a problem where the transparent pixels (alpha channel) from Canvas is not sent via Webrtc and will be replaced by black pixels. I know this is a known issue on Webrtc, here is a link [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=524218[]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=524218). Since Webrtc technology is iterating in a high pace I wonder if anyone knows of work- around for this issue?

Apparently, there is a fix for that [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/1737253002/), It is stated in there that:

> This CL changes the output frame format in canvas capture from
>   I420 to YV12A so that alpha channel is preserved.

unfortunately I cannot find a way how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal since WebRTC does not support alpha channel yet. WebRTC will convert pixel blocks into I420 pixel format which has 24 bit channel and does not have support for Alpha channel. On the other end , stream will be converted back to another pixel but alpha channel information will be lost.

Link is showing some private API implementation for Hangouts for Chromium project. I dont think it is related with WebRTC

i would recommend using web sockets if Alpha channel is must feature for now